# How to Manage Staging and Production Environments in a React Native App

Tags: react-native

I got a react-native app already ready and works but the app points on a prod api so to avoid problems I wanted that she points on a rest api, so how can I reconfigure it, I have only an environment file.js that contains the URL api, and this file is called in the API service

I tried react-native config but didn't know how to make it work,

All I want is to duplicate that env file because he contains all necessary URLs, so I want to have file named envProd and another named `envStaging` they should be similar the only different part is the URL of my api , so when I want to run the app i precise which file I want to choose to run with

Comment: Have you found the answer so far ?

Answer (score 0):

If the API URL's are the only difference, you don't need to create two separate config files. Instead, you can make use of the inbuild `__DEV__` global variable in JavaScript to determine if you're using React Native packager (dev mode) or not (production).

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html

So, something like below.

```
var apiURL = __DEV__ == true ? 'development.api.com' : 'prod.api.com';
```

Comment: You have not answered the question. The question is differentiating between "production" and "staging", not "development" and "staging". There is a huge different between these two.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding switching environments quite hard to manage.

`__DEV__` is awesome for local disabling stuff when in development. Won't work for any of the builds though.

For staging vs production seems that configuring react-native-config is the best. Unfortunately, next to being somewhat hard to configure binaries need to get recompiled separately for each environment. This means - one update - two build with uploads to whatever provider you use. It can get more complex if you use something like codepush too.

**possible solution**

Create a hidden feature in your app that allows to toggle the environment from the within the app. This way you can have one build, give it to testers. They switch env to staging and later you only need to promote it as a production build.

This could be something like tap 10 times on an empty space somewhere - the more creative you get the better :)

Good luck

Comment: The possible solution you have provided is not working due to asycstorage of react. It takes much time to fetch the flag. Any solution for async storage?

Answer (score 0):

```
const _Environments = {
  production: {
    API_BASE: 'https://api.test.com/',
    USERNAME: 'admin',
    PASSWORD: '1234',
  },
  development: {
    API_BASE: 'https://dev.api.test.com/',
    USERNAME: 'admin',
    PASSWORD: '1234',
  },
};

function getEnvironment() {
  // Insert logic here to get the current platform (e.g. staging, production, etc)
  var platform = __DEV__ ? 'development' : 'production';

  // ...now return the correct environment
  return _Environments[platform];
}

export const Environment = getEnvironment();
```

Comment: You have not answered the question. The question is differentiating between "production" and "staging", not "development" and "staging". There is a huge different between these two.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://medium.com/cwi-software/how-to-setup-multiple-environments-for-react-native-786005a360fc). using `yargs` you can replace static `import` content with dynamic scripts.